# ¿Cómo dinamizar los types e interfaces en typescript?

Tags: typescript, interface

Tengo algo que quiero realizar con los types e interfaces de Typescript.
Para explicarlo pondré el siguiente ejemplo:

```
interface IPayload {
variables: Array<{ name: string, age: number }>;
values: {// ¿Qué código poner para lograrlo?    }}

let data: Data = {
variables: [
       { name: 'Carlos', age: 17 },
       { name: 'Andres', age: 14 }],
values: {
    Carlos: { operation: 'Cambiar nombre', di: '/rename' },
    Andres: { operation: 'Buscar viajes', di: '/search' }
}}
```

Quiero que al momento de estar construyendo el objeto data me autocomplete los nombres de Carlos y Andres en ese caso. He leído la documentación de TS sobre eso y no he podido solucionar, si alguien sabe agradecería la ayuda.
Por el momento tengo la interfaz así:

```
interface Data {
variables: Array<{ name: string, age: number }>;
values: [n: string]: { operation: string; di: string };
```

}
Funciona pero no autocompleta por los nombres puestos.

Bueno respondiendo a lo que me han comentado, la pregunta viene ya que inquirer tiene algo parecido pensé que es posible construir, pero parece que es algo más complejo. Les daré una imagen donde se muestra:
Primera imagen muestra que autocompleta password que depende del valor de la propiedad type. Y lo mismo pasa con la segunda imagen.

[image: Primea muestra que autocompleta password.]
[image: En esta se muestra que autocompleta otro, que es el valor que le puse]

Intentaré comprender ese código y si llego a resolver algo les estaré contando.
Gracias por sus comentarios.

**Nota:** Edité la publicación ya que no se permite como añadir imagen en comentario.

Answer (score 0):

`values: [n: string]: { operation: string; di: string };` esta línea de código hace que values sea un objeto de multiples propiedades, es decir que puede tener carlos, andres, hola, adios, etc. cualquier cosa.

Para que te autocomplete tiene que saber que claves van a ir pero con esto perderías la parte dinámica

```
values: {Carlos:{operation:string,di:string}, Andres:{operation:string,di:string}}
```

Si quieres que tenga Carlos y Andres y además otras claves dinámicas puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
values: {Carlos:{operation:string,di:string}, Andres:{operation:string,di:string}, [k:string]:any}
```

Ahora si quieres que te autocomplete las claves a medida que le vas ingresando propiedades de forma dinámica esto no es posible, si bien typescript es una combinación de dinámico y estático hay cosas que no pueden combinarse

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no puedes conseguir nada más específico que lo que ya has creado, no hay modo de definir nombre de propiedades de manera dinámica.

Los tipos declarados en Typescript son una ayuda para detectar errores en tiempo de compilación, pero no existen en tiempo de ejecución. En tiempo de ejecución sólo tienes el Javascript resultante y nada comprueba que los valores cumplen con las condiciones dadas por los tipos. Por tanto, el valor de una variable no puede analizarse para definir el tipo de otra.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero.

Answer (score 0):

Muchachos encontré una solución muy aceptable con respecto a lo que había preguntado espero que les sirva, a quien esté con este tipo de actividad.

```
type IPayload<K extends string | number | symbol> = {
  variables: { name: K, age: number }[];
  values: Record<K, { operation: string, dir: string }>;
}

interface IUser {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}


const method: <K extends string>(params: IPayload<K>) => IPayload<K> = <K 
   extends string>(params: IPayload<K>) => {
   return params;
 }
const user = method({ variables: [{ age: 17, name: 'Carlos' }], values: { 
  Carlos: { dir: '/rename', operation: 'Cambiar nombre' } } });
```

[image: Autocompletado de la solución]